# django admin view image file not found

Tags: python, django

i am new here in `django`, I have uploaded image file, i can see file is uploaded under my app `myapp/mysite/uploads/testimonial/image.jpg` file is there, so it is correct, but now when i open that testimonial module in admin, and when i edit that testimonial and click on that view image link it is showing that as this link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/uploads/testimonial/image.jpg`, but that is not visible, can anyone please help me why that image is not showing, i am using python `version 3.6`, here i have mention whole my code, can anyone please look into it and help me to resolve this issue ?

models.py

```
class Testimonial(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    TESTIMONIAL_STATUS = ((1, 'Active'), (0, 'Inactive'))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = HTMLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/testimonial')
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TESTIMONIAL_STATUS, default=1)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `upload_to` field to:

```py
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='testimonial')
```

Remember [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) is a path relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`. The string value will be appended to your `MEDIA_ROOT` path.

If you want to try it out, follow the steps in [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: i just uploaded file, http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/testimonial/images_dLVS3pd.jpeg but still that image is not showing

Comment: Do i need to change in urls.py ?

Comment: Can you find the file in the folder?

Comment: Good, then the location is correct. You might want to take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development